# Slice and push to a 2D array with strings and numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to format data in an array that has both strings and numbers into a new array which I've managed to do with the code below however `Data` has both strings and numbers in it and when i use the code below it converts the numbers to strings.

Is there any way to get it to stay as a number?

```
data = [[VD, 20180427000000, 25528], [VD, 20180427000500, 25607].....] //go on like this for a few 300 odd rows.
n = 1
Linearray = [];
while (n < (data.length)-2) {
    DailyDemand = j( data[n].slice(1,3));
    Linearray.push(DailyDemand);        
    n++
};
```

Just to clarify the `data[0][1]` should be a string and `data [0][2]` should be an int.

Any help would be apprecated.

Comment: `it converts the numbers to strings. ` that depends on `j` which is not in your code.

Comment: I highly recommend against implicitly creating global variables.

Comment: Note that arrays are zero based, so `n=1` will skip the first index and `slice(1, 3)` will copy the second to fourth element.

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks for that. It's what i get for being lazy and copying and pasting code without looking at it properly. Also `n=1` because i need it to skip the header of the CSV file that i'm getting the data from. thanks again.